# Constructing 2D Half-Plane Given 3 Points, Choosing Outward Normal Every Time

Tags: c++, graphics, 2d, clip

Edit: added ASCII diagrams showing parameters in relation to half-plane

I have a HalfPlane class that defines a homogeneous representation of a half-plane in 2D space such that any point dot the homogeneous coordinate greater than 0 is outside the plane.

I am using this class to clip line segments for software rendering as well as point-triangle collision checking.

Given two points on the boundary line and a point within the half-plane, it is possible to find that homogeneous coordinate, but finding this first requires finding an outward-facing normal from the line.

This is the current implementation for finding a half-plane given a line segment and a point inside the half-plane, which assumes the normal it finds is the outwardly-facing normal.

```
// Hcoord is a Vector3
// Point  is a Vector3 such that w is always 1
// Vector is a Vector3 such that w is always 0
// HalfPlane is an aggregation of Hcoord and a few constructors

  // Half-Plane definition
  // n = <a, b>:  Outward-facing normal of the half-plane
  // C = (x, y):  Point on the boundary line
  // d = n dot C: Constant derived from normal form of the boundary line
  // [  a ]
  // [  b ] = half-plane AB containing P
  // [ -d ] 
  // the dot product of this Hcoord with any Point determines which
  // side of the half plane the Point resides

//              ^
//              | n
//   outside    |
// <------------x---------->
//    inside    C

// given an outward-facing normal and a Point on the boundary line
// find -d and construct the half-plane
static Hcoord ConstructHP(const Vector& n, const Point& C)
{
  return Hcoord(n.x, n.y, -1.0f * (n.x * C.x + n.y * C.y));
}


//     outside
// <-x--------------x->
//   A  inside      B
//        x P

// Given 2 Points on the boundary line and a Point contained within the half-plane
// construct the half-plane. Assume P is not collinear with A and B
static Hcoord ConstructHP(const Point& A, const Point& B, const Point& P)
{
  // find vector normal to line AB
  // assume [ -dy ] is outwardly-facing normal 'n'
  //        [  dx ]
  Vector n(A.y - B.y, B.x - A.x);


  // and construct HalfPlane based on that assumption
  Hcoord h(ConstructHP(n, A));

  // h dot P should be less than 0 
  // because P is within the half-plane
  if (dot(h, P) > 0)
    // if not, invert the half-plane
    h = -h;

  return h;
}
```

ConstructHP is an overloaded helper function called by the constructors of the HalfPlane class that take in identical parameters.

Given that I am handed arbitrary points that are assumed to be not collinear, is it possible to choose which normal to the half-plane to be the outwardly facing one without first constructing a presumed half-plane? If so, how?

In other words, I am looking for an algorithm that constructs the half-plane without the need for checking whether the half-plane that I construct is correct before returning it.

edit: I am rejecting `A-P` onto `A-B` in order to find the outward-facing normal now. ConstructHP with 3 points now has the following implementation:

```
static Hcoord ConstructHP(const Point& A, const Point& B, const Point& P)
{
  // find the outward facing normal by 
  // rejecting A - P onto A - B
  // and call outward normal + point constructor
  return ConstructHP(Rejection(A - P, A - B), A);
}

static Vector Rejection(const Vector& a, const Vector& b)
{

  //                              a dot b
  // a2 Rejection(a, b): a2 = a - ------- * b
  //                              b dot b
  return a - (dot(a, b) / dot(b, b)) * b;
}
```

Comment: You want [`P-A` rejected on `B-A`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection#Vector_rejection_2) (or the inverse of that), right?

Comment: As long as the solution avoids branching and reassigning values to `h`, anything should do fine. This is code is going to be executed on numerous times while iterating over faces of meshes when doing point-mesh collision.

Comment: That wasn't really a question. I was pushing you into the right direction.

Comment: Okay, I am now rejecting `A-P` (a) onto `B-A` (b) in order to call the other constructor with `Vector n = a - (dot(a, b) / dot(b, b)) * b` and `A`. I don't know if there are any optimizations that can be made.